# QuickBook Custom Field data importation - how to find the XML tag name?

Tags: xml, quickbooks

We have a program that fetches PO data from a server, and convert to Sales Order, and import into Quick Book. Now we add a custom field to the Sales Order.

In order to import the data in the custom field from a PO, how can I know destination XML tag name for the field? Let's say, I created a custom field ABCD in date format for Sales Order.

Would the XML tag be [ABCD] [/ABCD]? I don't think it would be that simple, but how could I figure out?

Also, do I need to run a script to prepare the field for data import, after creating a custom field from a screen?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a tag that is created for the custom fields. Instead, you use the tag `<DataExt>` tag. Inside this tag you have the `<OwnerID>` tag, which would be 0 to use the custom fields, the `<DataExtName>` tag to specify the name (i.e. ABCD), and the `<DataExtValue>` for the value of the field.

Keep in mind that you can have custom fields on the Sales Order as well as custom fields on the items on a Sales Order, so make sure you include it in the right section for the field that you want to use.

```
<DataExt>
    <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
    <DataExtName>ABCD</DataExtName>
    <DataExtValue>SomeValue</DataExtValue>
</DataExt>
```